# Алиас в OpenServer

Tags: openserver

мне надо показать сайт, который лежит на локальном сервере через форвардинг
Использую ngrok
И когда он генерирует ссылку, я перехожу на нее в окне появляется это:

Упс?! ;-)
Как вы здесь оказались?
Для перенаправления IP на нужный домен создайте алиас в настройках.

В алиас я прописываю в исходный домен свой внешний ip, а в конечный домен 
папку в которой лежит мой сайт.
localhost удалил в domains, и IP-адрес сервера тоже прописал свой внешний IP, но не помогает.

Помогите

Comment: Внешний ip компании или роутера? Если роутера, то надо делать проброс портов

Answer (score 1):

Потратил на эту проблему немало времени, но все же нашел ответ.

Нужно в настройках добавить алиас:

```
*.ngrok.io    =>    <Ваш домен>
```

Потом запустить ngrok с командой:

```
ngrok.exe http 80
```

Все, ссылка должна работать.